# How to check if zip file is empty in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

How can I verify if the zip file is empty or not ? I cannot use if -s in bash as the zip file is not always zero in size. if the zip file has empty directories in it, I want to delete the file else extract the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Info-ZIP tools installed (`zip`, `unzip`, `zipinfo`) you can use `zipinfo` on the zip file and just send the output to `/dev/null`. The status will be 0 if the file is not empty.

So:

```
if zipinfo foo.zip > /dev/null; then
    echo not empty
else
    echo empty
fi
```

Comment: this was giving me the same return code but I tweaked the above a little bit. add | grep ^- to look for files and then delete the file if $? is 1. Thank you Laurence

Comment: +1 I'd never heard of zipinfo before. @nlrreddy If Laurence solved your issue, feel free to accept his answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: zipinfo can potentially fail with exit code 1 for other reasons than an empty zip file. If you just look for exit code 1 you are in for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `zipinfo -t foo.zip` the exit status (from `$?`)will give an error if the zip file has nothing in it. In the version I'm running (3.00) this will be `1` but I imagine that's just a general error code, so the ambiguity might cause you other problems.

You'll also have to deal with the text output of the command which is a string with basic info about the file. I believe this answer is similar to one of those above.

**Edit:** If you want to avoid the ambiguous return value (and you're in the mood for `grep`) you could grep the output of the above command for "Empty zipfile".

Answer (score 0):

If you have `jar` installed you can use the `-t` option:

```
jar -tvf file.zip
```

Directores will all have trailing slashes so you can pipe it to `grep`:

```
if jar -tvf file.zip | egrep -v '/$' > /dev/null; then # we have some files!
  unzip file.zip
else
  rm -f file.zip
fi
```

Comment: is it possible with pure bash scripting without even using java jar ?

Comment: @nlrreddy See my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Empty zip files can be detected by their content. To check for this, you can e.g. compare by hash or content equality.

```
# Check by byte-content
$ diff <(echo -ne '\x50\x4b\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00') mytest.zip
# Check by hash
$ md5sum -c <<<"76cdb2bad9582d23c1f6f4d868218d6c mytest.zip"
mytest.zip: OK
```

Counter-intuitively, you can create an empty zip file for testing only with the `-i "*"` option of zip. If it's not present, zip will complain and exit with error code 1 on creation.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/mytest
$ cd /tmp/mytest
$ zip -r mytest.zip . -i "*"
```

This enables you to check the properties you desire:

```
$ md5sum mytest.zip 
76cdb2bad9582d23c1f6f4d868218d6c  mytest.zip
$ sha512sum mytest.zip 
5e2f959f36b66df0580a94f384c5fc1ceeec4b2a3925f062d7b68f21758b86581ac2adcfdde73a171a28496e758ef1b23ca4951c05455cdae9357cc3b5a5825f  mytest.zip
$ base64 mytest.zip
UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
$ hexdump -C mytest.zip 
00000000  50 4b 05 06 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |PK..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00                                 |......|
00000016
```